# What is materialization of RDDS in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have been searching for what materialization means, and I keep getting links to persist() functions. But more fundamentally and conceptually, what does materialization of Rdds help in and what is it?

Comment: Conception and fundamentals are too broad to discuss on the site, you'll need to read the original paper about RDDs. Materialization, in this context, means that data will be physically present on a storage level

Comment: This is in context of what? RDDs are not "materialized" until and unless an "action" is called upon them. Prior to that it's just a bunch of "transformations" getting stacked over each other in the form of a DAG. As soon as an action is called, the DAG is processed, all transformations are performed actively and you get a result. Search for "lazy evaluation" for more details .

Comment: @philantrovert in the context of a computer computing framework :)

Answer (score 0):

When we need to do different computations on the same dataframe, Spark recomputes the dataframe each time. This isn't an optimized approach.

*Materialize* is a Spark *action*. This reports Spark the dataframe has already been computed. Once a dataframe is materialized, Spark skips all stages before the materialize when the dataframe is reused later.

**Caching/Persisting** of dataframes is lazy. The first time the dataset is computed in an action, it will be kept in memory on the nodes. **Materialize** is an action that runs a job that produces the rows of data that a data frame represents, and returns a new data frame with the result. When the result data frame is used, Spark resumes execution using the data from the last shuffle.

Also, By reusing shuffle data, materialized data is served by the cluster's persistent shuffle servers instead of Spark executors. This makes materialize more reliable. Caching on the other hand happens in the executor where the task runs and data could be lost if executors time out from inactivity or run out of memory.

Refer to the JIRa ticket for detailed explanation [Materialize data frames](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-28188#:%7E:text=Materialize%20is%20a%20Spark%20action,two%20queries%20load%20different%20columns.)